# jQuery bind() - Prevent HTML click event from firing if LI click event fires

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my js, I have two click bindings:

```
$('#menu > li').bind('click', function () {...});
```

and

```
$('html').bind('click', function () {...});
```

They each do something slightly different depending on which is clicked.  The problem is, a click on an LI is also a click on HTML, so when I click on LI, both the LI click and HTML click events fire.

If I click anywhere other than an LI, I get only the HTML click, as desired.

Is there any way to say, basically, "*If the user clicked on an LI element, do this.  Else, if the user clicked anywhere else other than an LI, do that*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is prevent event bubbling. Using jQuery it's as simple as adding `e.stopPropagation()` inside your `li` event handler.

So your updated code would look like this:

```
$('#menu > li').bind('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...
});
```

Further Reading:

https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: That worked marvelously!  Thank you!  If you have some extra time, could you explain what provides the function event argument "e"?

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace jQuery automatically calls your bind function with the event object. The event object holds specific information about the event that is getting fired. For example: on an onkeypress event the event object (in your case named e)  would hold the actual key pressed jQuery has a nice accessor for this as well called (to normalize cross browser access) e.which. Hope that helps. Here is a nice article for more info: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html